# Next Page Link shows same posts on custom template

Tags: nextpage

I have a Page, with Custom Page Template to display 6 "Posts" with a specific category on that page.

I have tried:

```
<div class="navigation">
<div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous Entries') ?></div>
<div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('Next Entries &raquo;','') ?></div>
</div>
```

But it shows same posts and not other posts, however the URL changes to page/1/ page/2 and so on.

What do i intend to have:

I want to have Next link to be displayed on the template and when it is clicked, the next set of Posts with same Category should load.

I tried to google for a solution can stumbled upon this post: http://blog.deconcept.com/2005/02/07/wordpress-next-previous-post-links/ the solution used here is deprecated.

Comment: Please don't use third party services to add your code, add code directly to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the "$paged" variable. This controls the pagination, along with the "posts_per_page" option you have set.

Please see the following amended PasteBin: http://pastebin.com/U4teTA0F

This ensures that the correct page is set when using "/page/2". "/page/3", etc.

Code:

```
<div id="blogposts">

    <?php
        global $paged;
        $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=1&posts_per_page=6&paged=' . $paged );
        while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
    ?>
        <ul>
            <div id="post" style="max-width:400px;height:410px;border:solid thin red;   float:left;margin: 70px 30px 35px;">
            <p style="font-weight: bolder;"><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></p><h3 style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 12%; overflow: hidden;" ><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(350,250)); // Crop 300 by 200 px image?> 
            <div id="para" style="width=350 height=233"><p style="margin: 4px 15px 9px 17px; max-width: 90%; max-height: 64px; overflow: hidden;"><?php the_excerpt(); ?><?php do_action( 'addthis_widget' ); ?></p>


            </div>
        </ul>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

</div>
<?php global $paged; query_posts('paged='.$paged);?>
<div class="clear"></div>   
<div class="navigation"><p><?php posts_nav_link(); ?></p></div>     

</div>
```

Comment: Hey @Matty Thanks a lot for the change. Now its working perfectly. Indeed .paged was essential.
Ill make sure to add full code henceforth, was under impression that rules here are similar to that of Wordpress.org forums.